# Automatic app deployment to Amazon store

Tags: android, continuous-deployment, amazon-appstore

I've got multiple Android apps that are currently distributed via Google Play and the Amazon store. My goal is to automate the app upload process to minimize the time required to upload a new update. I've already done that for Google Play by using the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/).

Is there an equivalent API for the Amazon store for uploading new app versions or do I have reverse engineer the data send by the browser and develop an API library based on that?

I already searched but didn't found anything like that (except for the Amazon cloud deployment API).

Comment: Since nobody could answer this question I started to write a library for uploading APKs to Amazon. I will post the link here when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a slightly older post, but since I ended up here I'll add my two cents.

It looks like there is an Amazon Developer Publishing API available [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/manage/developer-publishing), but I'm not able to try it out yet because it requires developers to request API access. Once I hear back from Amazon, I'll update this answer with more details as to why it does or does not work well with my deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems like they finally added an API. I've already developed a tool that uses selenium to upload new apps via the browser interface. Might be the right time to change to the real api :-)