# Automatically building and deploying React Native app using Jenkins?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, react-native, jenkins, command-line

Packaging my little react native app for Android so that it runs e.g. with [Expo](https://github.com/expo/expo) on an online App testing service like [Appetize](https://appetize.io/) or [Runthatapp](http://www.runthatapp.com/) is easy. Up to now I relied on online services to do the building for me, but that is no sustainable solution, that's why I want to do it on my own now.

I understand that for compiling my react native app for iOS I have to somehow run Xcode (on a virtual box). I am able use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) to build my APK files using the GUI, but how do I do that automatically?

I am looking for a way how to automatize that process using Jenkins (either under Ubuntu or under Windows). How would I approach that? My architectural idea looks as follows:

- **Step 1.** Jenkins pulls source code and additional artwork (i.e. logos) from GIT
- **Step 2.** Building and packaging.

  - **2.1** Jenkins initiates the Android Studio and starts building the `.apk`-file, ideally via command line.
  - **2.2** Jenkins initiates Xcode with some fancy long command line, and out comes 
    a nice `.ipa` file.
- **Step 3.** Jenkins takes both files and archives them
- **Step 4.** Deployment

  - **4.1** Jenkins automatically deploys to Google Play Store using their API
  - **4.2** Jenkins automatically deploys to Apple App Store using their API
  - **4.3** Jenkins automatically deploys it to the Amazon App Store.

I am struggling with step 2 and 4, but the priority is the automatic building (step 2). Any help is appreciated, even links to tutorials. What I am after is an explanation on who to steer Android Studio and Xcode by command line.

**Resources**

- [How to run apk file online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871652/how-to-run-apk-file-online)
- [What is the (file) format of iOS/iPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898723/)
- [Deploy to Google Play Store via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153708/deploy-to-google-play-store-via-api)
- [Automatic app deployment to Amazon store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019871/automatic-app-deployment-to-amazon-store)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107024/is-there-any-official-way-or-api-to-get-app-reviews-for-ios-apps
- [Deploy/Publish Android app made with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783344/deploy-publish-android-app-made-with-react-native)
- [Unable to build APK file on Jenkins (react native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940596/)